# dynamic ec2 resourcing in declarative cloud formation/terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud, aws-cloudformation

We are moving our infrastructure to cloud formation since it's much easier to describe the infrastructure in a nice manner. This works fantastically well for things like security groups, routing, VPCs, transit gateways.

However, we have two issues which we are struggling with and I don't think fit the declarative, infrastructure-as-code paradigm which things like terrafrom and cloud formation are.

(1) We have a business requirement where we run a scheduled batch at specific times in the day. These are very computationally intensive. To save costs, we run these on an EC2 which is brought up at that time, then torn down when the batch is finished. However, this seems to require a temporary change to the terraform/CF files, then a change back. Is there a more native way of doing this?

(2) We dynamically store and allow to be edited by clients their firewalling rules on their load balancer (ALB). This information cannot be stored in the terraform/CF files since it can be changed by clients on demand.

Is there a way of properly doing these things in CF/Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you have to use EC2, you could create a Lambda that would start your EC2 instances. Then, create a CloudWatch Event that triggers the Lambda at your specified date / time. For more details you can see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/. Once the job is done, have your EC2 shut itself down using the awssdk or awscli.

Alternatively, you could use AWS Lambda to run your batch job. You only get charged when the Lambda runs. Likewise, create a CloudWatch Event rule that schedules the Lambda.

(2) You could store the firewall rules in your own DB and modify the actual ALB SG rules using the awssdk. I don't think it's a good idea to store these things in Terraform/CF. IMHO Terraform/CF are great for declaring infrastructure but won't be a good solution for resources that are dynamically changing, especially by third parties like your clients.

Comment: Can you run arbitrary binaries in AWS Lambda?

Comment: @Nick I believe it's possible! See this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/